# User Authorization in KohanaPHP App vs Endless Loop

Tags: redirect, kohana

Wondering how to name this question. Think this is the best situation possible.

Situation:
I got small app written in KohanaPHP framework. However there's one small bug that makes my crazy.

I got my own Core_Controller that is extended by every controller in this app. In constructor of this controller, I'm checking user profile status. So far so good. Although I'm facing a logical issue. It's called endless redirect loop. If I try to redirect (in Core_Controller constructor) user to Member_Controller it cannot be workig due to endless lopp. I understand why it happen.

Solution:
I'm looking for a solution how to make it flexible. I tried to move this verification to a helper and call it in Core_Controller constructor. However, it can be working correctly.

Question:
Do I have to put verification in constructor of every single controller? IS there any universal method to do it?

Waiting for your thoughts.

M.A.

Comment: I was also trying to use a base controller (http://docs.kohanaphp.com/general/controllers#using_a_base_controller_for_your_application). With the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if user is verified and the current request's action isn't something like member/verification, do the redirect.

And `parent::__construct();` will call the parent constructor, so I don't see the problem in that either..

Answer (score 0):

You need a condition where it doesn't redirect (on the page you have redirected to). You'll want some code similar to this.

```
if not member_controller then
    redirect to member_controller
else
    do nothing
endif
```

The else isn't needed, but just added so it's more clear to you.